# Integrating HerzultForumBundle in Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, forum

I have installed the [HerzultFourmBundle](https://github.com/Herzult/HerzultForumBundle) into my Symfony2 application, added the calls in the app kernel and auto load and extended the base classes.  The problem i am having is i have a site layout that is applied to every page in the application and i want to render the forum within this.

I am very new to Symfony and PHP, but i have tried a few ways to get this working.  I have a controller method set up that will render the forum page correctly which is set through the normal routing configuration, i can also set it up so that is routes to the index method in the Forum controller in the Herzult forum bundle.  However this renders the default styles for the forum index page and is not contained by the layout i require.

Can someone provide me with an example of how to implement the forum and integrate it into a site?  A simple example would point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at bundle's [main layout file](https://github.com/Herzult/HerzultForumBundle/blob/master/Resources/views/layout.html.twig#L1) you'll notice that it extends '::base.html.twig' template:

```
{% extends '::base.html.twig' %}
```

This is an application level template located in `apps/Resources/viewsbase.html.twig` file. 
You should be able to define your custom stuff as long as you're using this template.

This is a convention called "Three level template inheritance". Read more about it in the documentation: http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/book/templating.html#three-level-inheritance

Note that HerzultForumBundle is currently under intensive development. Some features might be missing.

Comment: Thanks, i still had some issues with the blocks defined in our base twig but i have got it sorted now through a combination of reading the documentation and looking at the bundle code.